# How does layout work in a CoordinatorLayout?

Tags: android, coordinator-layout

How do views position in the CoordinatorLayout? for example...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
       <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
           android:id="@+id/toolbar"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
           app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"></android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
   </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

   <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
       android:id="@+id/scroll"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
       android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
       app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/description"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="@string/hello_world" />
   </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>    
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

If I filled its child text view a 1000 lines, then it would appear correct and the text would start just below the appbarlayout.

However as it only shows hello world it appears at the bottom of the screen.
No idea why.

Any ideas?

Comment: Post screenshots please

Comment: can you try adding android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical" to your nestedScrollView. Some have reported it to be a bug in 22.2.0 maybe an update may also help.

Comment: Correct @hars thats helped. thanks very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the height of NestedScrollView is android:layout_height="wrap_content" so it shows the content at bottom. You just need to change your NestedScrollView height to `android:layout_height="match_parent"` like this :

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"></android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/description"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/hello_world" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

It looks like this :

[image]

Comment: Oops I missed that!
However if you were to try and scroll "hello world" the toolbar disappears as it should do, but hello world moves to the bottom of the screen.

Comment: @aidanmack aceept as correct answer if it helps you.

Comment: also needs android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical" 
added to the Nest scroll view to stop it from appearing at the bottom on scroll

sorted. thanks guys.